# How to optimise mysql query as Full ProcessList is showing Sending Data for over 24 hours

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I have the following query that runs forever and I am looking to see if there is anyway that I can optimise it. This is running on a table that has in total 1,406,480 rows of data but apart from the Filename and Refcolumn, the ID and End_Date have both been indexed.

My Query:

```
INSERT INTO UniqueIDs
    (
    SELECT
        T1.ID
    FROM
        master_table T1
    LEFT JOIN
        master_table T2
    ON
    (
        T1.Ref_No = T2.Ref_No
    AND
        T1.End_Date = T2.End_Date
    AND
        T1.Filename = T2.Filename
    AND
        T1.ID > T2.ID
    )
    WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
    AND
        LENGTH(T1.Ref_No) BETWEEN 5 AND 10
    )
    ;
```

Explain Results:
[image]

The reason for not indexing the Ref_No is that this is a text column and therefore I get a BLOB/TEXT error when I try and index this column.

Would really appreciate if somebody could advise on how I can quicken this query.

Thanks

---

Thanks to Bill in regards to multi column indexes I have managed to make some headway. I first ran this code:

```
CREATE INDEX I_DELETE_DUPS ON master_table(id, End_Date);
```

I then added a new column to show the length of the Ref_No but had to change it from the query Bill mentioned as my version of MySQL is 5.5. So I ran it in 3 steps:

```
ALTER TABLE master_table
ADD COLUMN Ref_No_length SMALLINT UNSIGNED;

UPDATE master_table SET Ref_No_length = LENGTH(Ref_No);

ALTER TABLE master_table ADD INDEX (Ref_No_length);
```

Last step was to change my insert query with the where clause for the length. This was changed to:

```
AND t1.Ref_No_length between 5 and 10;
```

I then ran this query and within 15 mins I had 280k worth of id's inserted into my UniqueIDs table. I did go change my insert script to see if I could add more values to the length by doing the following:

```
AND t1.Ref_No_length IN (5,6,7,8,9,10,13);
```

This was to bring in the values where length was also equal to 13. This query took a lot longer, 2hr 50 mins to be precise but the additional ask of looking for all rows that have length of 13 gave me an extra 700k unique ids.

I am looking at ways to optimise the query with the IN clause, but a big improvement where this query kept running for 24 hours. So thank you so much Bill.

Comment: The length function is unfortunate as it prohibits the use of an index. If ref no is an integer then there exists an obvious improvement

Comment: ("Sending Data" is a useless piece of non-information.)

Comment: Michael, AND t1.Ref_No_length between 5 and 13; rather than using the IN list with the skip of 11 and 12 would likely complete quicker.

Answer (score 0):

For the JOIN, you should have a multi-column index on `(Ref_No, End_Date, Filename)`.

You can create a [prefix index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-indexes.html#column-indexes-prefix) on a TEXT column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE master_table ADD INDEX (Ref_No(10));
```

But that won't help you search based on the LENGTH(). Indexing only helps search by value indexed, not by functions on the column.

In MySQL 5.7 or later, you can create a virtual column like this, with an index on the values calculated for the virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE master_table
  ADD COLUMN Ref_No_length SMALLINT UNSIGNED AS (LENGTH(Ref_No)),
  ADD INDEX (Ref_No_length);
```

Then MySQL will recognize that your condition in your query is the same as the expression for the virtual column, and it will automatically use the index (exception: in my experience, this doesn't work for expressions using JSON functions).

But this is no guarantee that the index will help. If most of the rows match the condition of the length being between 5 and 10, the optimizer will not bother with the index. It may be more work to use the index than to do a table-scan.

Comment: Thank you Bill for your response. Will go through your suggestions and post how I get on.

Comment: Bill, was creating the virtual column like you mentioned but kept getting an error message. Think its down to my version MySQL which is 5.5.27 and you mentioned that only works for 5.7 and above.

Comment: I also added a multi column index without the Ref_No as that failed on the BLOB/TEXT error again. Added an Index for the Ref_No using the first Alter Table code but this has increased the rows when I look my Explain query to 1471073.

Comment: The `rows` output in the EXPLAIN is just an estimate. It can be higher or lower than the actual number of rows it will actually read, but it's usually correct within an order of magnitude.

Comment: Do you really need to use TEXT for the `Ref_No` column? I'm making an assumption, but I would think a column of that name would have pretty short strings in it, or maybe even a number.

Comment: The reason for using TEXT for the Ref_No was due to cleansing reasons. The column is supposed to only have numbers but due to typing errors and other characters as the database has been populated from a number of csv files. I have managed to make some progress. Will post on the original question with my code.

Comment: Typing errors that require Ref_No to store strings up to 64KB? I would think even if you need a string, one with a shorter length would suffice. I'm asking because you _can_ index a shorter string column.

Answer (score 0):

> the ID and End_Date have both been indexed.

You have `PRIMARY KEY(id)` and *redundantly* `INDEX(id)`?  A PK is a unique key.

"have both been indexed" -- `INDEX(a), INDEX(b)` is not the same as `INDEX(a,b)` -- they have different uses.  Read about "composite" indexes.

That query smells a lot like "group-wise" max done in a very slow way.  (Alas, that may have come from the online docs.)

I have compiled the fastest ways to do that task here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max  (There are multiple versions, based on MySQL version and what issues your code can/cannot tolerate.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  One important question: Is `id` the PRIMARY KEY?

This composite index may be useful:

```
(Filename, End_Date, Ref_No,  -- first, in any order
 ID)    -- last
```

This, as others have noted, is unlikely to be helped by any index, hence T1 will need a full-table-scan:

```
AND  LENGTH(T1.Ref_No) BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

If `Ref_No` cannot be bigger than 191 characters, change it to a `VARCHAR` so that it can be used in an index.  Oh, did I ask for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?  If you can't make it `VARCHAR`, then my recommended composite index is

```
INDEX(Filename, End_Date, ID)
```

Comment: Rick thank you for looking at this. Will go through what you have written to see what further improvements I can make.